# Can't Use Nil for keys or values of PFObject

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, int

So I have this code.

```
@IBAction func updateRatelabel(sender: AnyObject) {
    let rateValue = Int(rateSlider.value)
    if rateValue == 0 {
        rateLabel.text = "Budget (min.)"
    }
    else {
        rateLabel.text = "$ \(rateValue)"
    }
}

func createdoctor()
{
    let doctors =  PFObject(className: "doctors")
    if doctorName.text?.characters.count > 5 {
        doctorName.textColor = UIColor.redColor()   
    }
    else {
        let currentUser  = String( PFUser.currentUser())

        let rateValue =  rateLabel.text
        let rateValueInt = String(rateValue?.characters.dropFirst(2))
        print(rateValueInt)

        doctors["doctorName"] = doctorName.text
        doctors["Rate"] = Int(rateValueInt)
        doctors["doctorContent"] = doctorDetails.text
        doctors["createdby"] = currentUser
        doctors.saveInBackgroundWithBlock ({(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("created doctor")
            }
            else {
                print("image \(error)")
            }
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "New doctor Created" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        })
    }
}
```

I am getting error when this code kicks in, this is the error that is happening

```
> 016-01-31 01:00:07.921 idoctortwo[3294:151254] Attempting to load the
> view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and
> may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7f8258c8af80>)
> Optional(Swift.String.CharacterView(_core:
> Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x00007f8258c9b9c2, _countAndFlags: 4,
> _owner: Optional(Swift._HeapBufferStorage<Swift._StringBufferIVars, Swift.UInt16>)))) 2016-01-31 01:00:12.771 idoctortwo[3294:151254] ***
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or
> values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'
```

I managed to find out that the following line of code is the culprit

```
doctors["Rate"] = Int(rateValueInt)
```

if I do this

```
doctors["Rate"] = rateValueInt
```

I have no error but my Parse the column is a number column hence the effort to make it as a number.

EDIT

> 2016-01-31 03:58:11.222 iLegaltwo[3662:186816] Attempting to load the
>   view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and
>   may result in undefined behavior ()
>   Optional(Swift.String.CharacterView(_core:
>   Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x00007fb2c3667472, _countAndFlags: 4,
>   _owner: Optional(Swift._HeapBufferStorage)))) 2016-01-31 03:58:30.728 iLegaltwo[3662:186900]
>   [Error]: invalid type for key createdby, expected *_User, but got
>   string (Code: 111, Version: 1.12.0) image Optional(Error Domain=Parse
>   Code=111 "invalid type for key createdby, expected *_User, but got
>   string" UserInfo={code=111, temporary=0, error=invalid type for key
>   createdby, expected *_User, but got string,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=invalid type for key createdby, expected
>   *_User, but got string})

EDIT after modifications for the above error:

```
func createCase()
    {
          let cases =  PFObject(className: "Cases")
        if caseName.text?.characters.count > 5
        {

            caseName.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

        }
        else
        {

            let currentUser  = String( PFUser.currentUser())


            let rateValue =  rateLabel.text
            let rateValueInt = String(rateValue?.characters.dropFirst(2))
            print(rateValueInt)

        cases["CaseName"] = caseName.text
        cases["Rate"] = Int(rateValueInt) ?? Int(0)
        cases["CaseContent"] = caseDetails.text
            cases["createdby"] = currentUser
        cases.saveInBackgroundWithBlock ({(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                print("created case")
            }
            else
            {
                print("image \(error)")
            }
                self.performSelectorOnMainThread("success", withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
        })
        }


    }

    func success() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "New doctor Created" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You now have 2 different questions in a single post, which is a pitty: you can certainly +1 both, but you can't approve both..

Comment: I believe your second answer and my second question is the focus of this question, as I mentioned I managed to figure out how to get it INT yet facing with this ugly output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Can't touch the UI from the background thread

Push the view controller from the main thread. Culprit:

```
saveInBackgroundWithBlock...
    self.presentViewController
```

**Solutions**

```
- use `performSelectorOnMainThread`
- use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) { } })
```

**Example**

Replace alert creation by

```
self.performSelectorOnMainThread("success", withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

and add this method:

```
func success() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "New doctor Created" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: See my edited question (Edit 2), if that is about right, then unfortunately it is still having the same error.

Comment: Oh! I am sorry my bad! really sorry! I think u too might have overlooked it, the error message says _User and then if u notice i have this line of code.
 cases["createdby"] = currentUser

Comment: Well, stopping to covert the current user in to string has prevented the error! As the current user in my DB I have changed to pointer and I am trying to pass a String rather than the raw objectID hence I was getting that error. But glad u pointed me in the right direction, thankyou!

Comment: Indeed, I had overlooked `*_User, but got string` error!

Answer (score 1):

## Dictionary key/value can't be nil

`Int("someString")` doesn't return an `Int` but an optional `Int?`.

The [documentation](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html) lists these accessors as *Array Accessors*, while in reality, using **key/value**, they should be considered *Dictionary Accessors*.

Thus you should treat `PFObject` is a dictionary wrapper: can't pass *nil* for either key nor value. You store *objects* in a dictionary, not optionals.

**Twist**

`Int(rateValueInt)` ends up being a `Int?`, because of the `Int(rateValueInt)` conversion.

**Solution**

```
doctors["Rate"] = Int(rateValueInt) ?? Int(0)
```

This will explicitly substitute an `Int` in case `Int(rateValueInt)` can't be unwrapped.

Comment: But still getting this ugly error, please see edit to my question.

Comment: Not the same error, or a compounding error. Added a second response (one per error). You may need both.